# /etc/group declared seemingly wrongly, still works?

Tags: centos, group, etc

This is more of a clarification question than a problem.

I'm not a sysadmin, but out of curiosity I went through our config files and encountered this behavior.

This is on a *CentOS 5.8* system

**/etc/group:**

```
LN XX: <groupname>:x:<id>:<uname of another user>:<another user>:,<me>
```

As you can see, users are not delimited by ',' but ':', and before my username is both ':,'

I am defaultly a member of a different group.

The folder I am writing to and files/directories in it have permissions (775)

```
rwxrwxr-x
drwxrwxr-x
```

and its owner is another user from the group mentioned before.

The question I have is:

- Why can I write to this folder?  /etc/group is declared differently than in documentation, so I should be other, shouldn't I?
- Is there other place/way to add user to group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the line `/etc/group` line you supplied, there's a `,` before your name.  it's possible (but unlikely) that that Centos system is being quite liberal in how it parses /etc/group.

More likely, is that it's treating all the `:` separated usenames before yours as just one username, `<uname of another user>:<another user>:`...and your username is just the second member of that group.   That's what my (debian sid) system does if I create a bogus group similar to your example.

Comment: if you run `id <uname of another user>`, does it show them as a member of that group.   alternatively, run `members groupname` if you have that tool installed.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. The users before ',' are not in the group, whereas I am. Thank you.